# $f\in L^1(0,\infty)$ monotone, show $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} xf(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Here is the solution:

First $f$ is monotone and integrable on $(0,\infty)$, wolg we can assume that $f>0$ and approaches $0$ as $x$ goes to infinity. Observe that 
$$xf(2x) \leq \int_x^{2x} f(t)$$
since when $t\in [x,2x]$ we have $f(t) \geq f(2x)$ because $f$ is decreasing. And since $f$ is integrable, we have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \int_x^{2x} f(t) = 0,$$
thus
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} 2xf(2x) = 0.$$

Comment: The negation of "$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} xf(x)=0$" is not "$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} xf(x)>0$".

Comment: Your proof looks OK.

Comment: $x$ is monotone increasing and $f$ will have to be monotone decreasing. The product $xf(x)$ needn't be monotone. You can't claim that for *all* $x\ge x_0$, $xf(x) \ge\epsilon$. One can say at best that there's a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_nf(x_n) \ge\epsilon$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119409/if-monotone-decreasing-and-int-0-infty-fxdx-infty-then-lim-x-to-infty), though.

Comment: This argument is by contradiction, not contraposition.

Comment: Thank you guys for the reply! I remembered how I worked on this problem a few months ago. The result comes directly from the fact that 
$$xf(2x) \leq \int_x^{2x} f(t).$$ Now I will try to fix the hole in my contradiction proof.

Comment: could u please show the fact in detail...