# property about improper integrals

Tags: improper-integrals

Let be $f:[0,\infty[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a decreasing and continuos, $f(x)>0 , \forall x$. If $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} xf(x) = 0.$

How to prove that?

Ok, I know that if $G(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^{x}f(t)dt $ then $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} G(x) = L$, How can I use that for arrive in $xf(x)$??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If monotone decreasing and $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx < \infty$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} xf(x)=0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119409/if-monotone-decreasing-and-int-0-infty-fxdx-infty-then-lim-x-to-infty)