# Is it true that if $g$ is monotone on $(0,1]$ and $\int_0^1 x^k g$ exists for some $k>-1$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} x^{k+1} g(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Is it true that if $g$ is monotone on $(0,1]$ and $\int_0^1 x^k g$ exists for some $k>-1$, then $\lim_{x\to0} x^{k+1} g(x)=0$?

I can show that for any $\varepsilon>0$,
there is $\delta>0$ such that for any $0<a<b<\delta$,
we have $|\int_a^b x^k g(x) dx|<\varepsilon$.
However, the idea in [If monotone decreasing and $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx <\infty$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} xf(x)=0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119409/if-monotone-decreasing-and-int-0-infty-fxdx-infty-then-lim-limits-x-t?rq=1)
does not seem to apply here directly,
because $x^\alpha g$ may not be monotone,
but I also struggle to find a counterexample either.
Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $g(x)\ge 0$ and $g$ is decreasing. Then
$$\int\limits_0^xt^kg(t)\,dt\ge g(x)\int\limits_0^xt^k\,dt={1\over k+1}x^{k+1}g(x)\ge 0$$
Therefore $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{k+1}g(x)=0.$

If $g(x)\ge 0$ and $g$ is increasing then the conclusion holds obviously as $x^{k+1}\to 0$ and $g(x)$ has a finite limit when $x\to 0^+.$