# Convergence of $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ implies $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = 0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

Here is the question I am trying to answer:

> Let $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a monotone increasing function. Prove that if the improper integral $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ exists, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = 0$.

I am aware that there are proofs of stronger statements (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119409/if-monotone-decreasing-and-int-0-infty-fxdx-infty-then-lim-limits-x-t)). However, those proofs do not help prove the given statement.

My first guess was to try proving the contrapositive, but that involves many cases. If $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) \ne 0$, then it could diverge, oscillate, or converge to some other value. I think the fact that $f$ is monotone increasing could help eliminate some of these cases.

That being said, I feel like a direct proof is possible and probably more simple. Some observations I have made,

- If $f$ is monotone increasing and the improper integral converges, then $f$ must be negative.
- Seeing as we do not know the value of the improper integral, Cauchy Criterion might be useful
- The converse of the statement is not true.

Comment: How does a proof of a stronger statement not prove the given statement?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I am trying to prove the given statement and I do not want to simply say, it follows from another theorem

Comment: If $f$ is monotone increasing, then as $x \to +\infty$ it either it diverges to $+\infty$ or converges.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not seeing how those proofs do not help, so I will have to vote to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: $f$ is monotone increasing, so if it is bounded from above, it converges. You said yourself $f$ has to be nonpositive. Assume its limit is strictly negative and see what happens.