# A question on convergent series of positive terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\sum a_n$ be a convergent series of positive terms ; then we know $\lim \inf (na_n)=0$ ; can we derive from here that if $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing , then $\lim (na_n)=0$ ?

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55649/does-f-monotone-and-f-in-l-1a-infty-imply-lim-t-to-infty-t-ft-0/

Comment: What about $a_n=\frac1n$? EDIT: Oh, you're only talking about sequences for which the sum converges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\displaystyle\epsilon > \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}a_k> na_{2n}$ for all $n > N$